# How to handling row level permissions in hbase

Tags: hbase

Obviously Hbase has no implicit way of doing this.  So my next thought was to do it using ACLs at the cell level.  Unfortunately I've only seen setting the ACLs for a specific user or a map of users/permissions.  Is there any way to allow users from a specific group to have permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Group names are prefixed using @ in the grant command.

```
grant '@mygroup', 'RW'
```

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/7qLndRsf2tQ) and [this](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Enabling+HBase+Access+Control) talks about it in more detail.

In [documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/hbase.accesscontrol.configuration.html) its given how to manage group roles but not much info for implementation, as below 8.2.2 - point 3

HBase managed "roles" as collections of permissions: We will not model "roles" internally in HBase to begin with. We instead allow group names to be granted permissions, which allows external modeling of roles via group membership. Groups are created and manipulated externally to HBase, via the Hadoop group mapping service.

Comment: Grant will only allow access at the column I was hoping to do it using something like the setACL in the put command as to do it on a row bases

Comment: Well, did [this](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.html#setACL%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.Permission%29) not work for you, giving user and permission? Example usage [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/03/hbase-098?utm_term=global&utm_reader=feedly&utm_content=bufferbe7d9&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer). As mentioned above, adding @ will make it a group rather than a single user

Comment: @Ramzy
 Hi,I have configured HBase-1.1.3 and Hadoop-2.7.2 with Kerberos security. I have enabled authorization for HBase. When executing any authorization command like user_permission, grant, revoke, etc. Its getting more than 40 seconds to display the result. Help me to improve performance on HBase acl. 
Thanks, Mathes